# Appium: Why can I not use the elements I find using xpath?

Tags: android, ruby, xpath, appium

```
cell_elements = find_elements(:xpath, '//*/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView[1]/*')
element = cell_elements[0]
element.value.should eq 'something'
```

The above code returns all the elements in the list view, but on line 3, when resolving `element.value` it fails with the following message:

> An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)

To me it doesn't make any sense that Appium is able to find the elements, but when trying to use one, it can't find it again. So this seems like a bug. I also tried this:

```
element = find_element(:xpath, "//*/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[0]")
element.value.should eq 'something'
```

That fails with the same error.

I don't have much experience with `xpath`, so just want to ask if I am doing anything wrong or if I should report this as a bug?

Comment: What does the output of `p cell_elements` look like?  Is it possible that `cell_elements[0]` is an array/hash?  Or, maybe `cell_elements` is an empty array??

Comment: If `cell_elements[0]` was an array or a hash, `element.value` would not raise that exception. Only an Appium element would do that.

Comment: @7stud `#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x4e732a05e79d5bec id="4">`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is misleading, it is not that the element does not exist, but that it has no `value` attribute.

This can be confirmed by getting the `text` of the element.

Comment: The docs say otherwise: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Element. Of course the op can test that with:  `puts element.respond_to? :value`

Comment: It was confirmed on Erik's machine that `element.value` results in this while `element.text` or `element.click` work perfectly.

Comment: Of course it may be something specific to this container type with this version of Appium with Android that it has no `value` of its own

Comment: I just tested selenium-webdriver in a stand alone ruby program--and there is no `value` attribute/method for me either: `undefined method 'value' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x007f8f41a6ec30> (NoMethodError)`.  Is the op's program working now?  If not, I posted a possible reason at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cell_elements = find_elements('//*/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView[1]/*', :xpath)   
> element = cell_elements[0]   
> element.value.should eq 'something'
> ```
>
> To me it doesn't make any sense that Appium is able to find the
>   elements, but when trying to use one, it can't find it again.

After reading your error message a little more carefully, it looks to me like there might be some lazy evaluation going on.  The first line requires no evaluation, e.g. selenium could just make a note: "I might need to retrieve these elements at some point, but not just yet."

Likewise for the second line, selenium could just make an additional note, "When I actually retrieve the elements specified on the first line, I need to return the first element."

But for the third line, selenium must actually do the evaluation (and stop being lazy).  The value of the first element is needed to compare it to the string 'something', so at that point selenium must evaluate the first line, but "*using the given search parameters*" the element couldn't be located.

That means something is the matter with your xpath.  Without knowing the structure of the thing you are trying to parse, it's hard to know what's wrong.  By the way, I think `//*/abc` is equivalent to `//abc`.

Looking through the selenium docs, it looks like you have the arguments for `find_elements()` reversed.

Comment: That is true, but I was using it through a helper method where the arguments are reversed to make the how optional.